Apache HTTP server потребляет всю память компьютера и вешает его при работе в Wordpress
Делаю первый сайт в Wordpress. Установил Open Server Panel. Проект запускаю через него. На компьютере 8ГБ оперативной памяти. Что, конечно, достаточно для работы с Wordpress. Но, каждый раз буквально после нескольких действий по созданию сайта процесс Apache HTTP server начинает потреблять всю свободную память компьютера и вешает его. Помогите кто сталкивался с такой проблемой.

Не используй "Open Server Panel" и вообще локальные виндовые недосерверы. Используй нормальный хостинг.

Спасибо за совет. Но, сорри, пока в этом плохо разбираюсь. Я так понимаю совет делать сайт сразу на хостинге. А как сделать сайт на компе локально и потом залить? Что для этого использовать?

Не надо никаких "локально". Делай сразу там, где сайт будет работать. На хостинге.

Предлагаю использовать для локальной разработке localWP , есть для Linux, Windows, Mac
Ваша проблема решена по дефолту, нужно просто перенести ваши сайты как вы их переносите на хостинг.
Ссылка на программу:
https://localwp.com/
Так же если у вас windows или Mac можно использовать решение от WordPress(Automatic):
https://developer.wordpress.com/studio/
